# Integrating a partial differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The boundary conditions are $P(r=r_e)=P_e$ and $P(r=r_w)=P_w$

$$\frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr}\left(r \frac{dP}{dr}\right)=0.$$

I know I have to integrate it twice but how?

The answer comes out to
$$P=P_w+\frac{P_e-P_w}{\ln(r_e/r_w)}\ln(r/r_w).$$

Comment: Why is this a PDE? $P$ is function which just depends on $r$? (There are no partial derivatives to be found...)

Comment: the parent equation is a PDE, after assumptions and simplifications this is what i end up with. Stuck at the last part which should have been the easiest. Drawing a blank now. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dP}{dr}) = rP^{\prime\prime}+P^\prime$. Let $Q = P^\prime$, so you have $Q^\prime +\frac{1}{r}Q = 0$. Solve the first order ODE for $Q$ then solve back for $P$. Plug in BC's and you should get your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dP}{dr}\right)=0$$

Then $$r\frac{dP}{dr}=c$$ where $c$ is a constant. Now separate the variables and integrate, getting $$P=c\ln r+k$$ where $k$ is also a constant.

Now apply the given conditions to obtain the two constants, and the result follows.